# How to give the Request.Querystring value to ImageURL in .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have many hyperlinks in my Page. If i click on a hyperlink it will take me to the respective page. I have given `Request.QueryString` value with the hyperlinks.
Now i want to give that `Request.QueryString` value as my ImageURL

I have given like

```
<asp:Image ID="NewsImage" runat="server"  
     ImageUrl='<%# GetImageURL() %>'   Width="100px" Height="100px"  />
```

Then in the coding side i have given like

```
public string GetImageURL()  
{  
     string imagename = Request.QueryString["News"] as string;    
     return "~/Images/" + imagename;  
}
```

But I am not getting the image in my output..
When i give `<asp:ImageButton` instead of `< asp:Image` then i am getting a error like **Submit Query** in the place where i have placed my ImageButton.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `ImageUrl='<%# GetImageURL() %>'` try this in Page_Load():

```
this.NewsImage.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + Request.QueryString["News"]
```

Note that you also are ripe for XSS with this approach.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: it is not suggesting me the imageID name in the codings side.... when i type this. na,then the imageId name is not coming. any idea about that ?

Comment: Is this `<asp:Image` inside a DataGrid or other repeater control?  If so, you'll need to use `.FindControl("NewsImage")` from within the `*_RowDataBound` event.

Comment: yeah thanks :) now i got it like NewsFormView.FindControl("NewsImage") ...... from here how to set the imageURL?

Comment: `Image img = NewsFormView.FindControl("NewsImage") as Image; img.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + Request.QueryString["News"];`  Note that this approach leaves you open to a cross-site scripting hole the size of city buildings.